# Wrong answer for 64 bit shift

Tags: c, gcc, bit-manipulation

Here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

int main()
{
    uint64_t a = 1000000000;
    printf("%" PRIu64 "\n", a << 40);
    return 0;
}
```

This code returns

```
11153727427136454656
```

The correct answer is `1099511627776000000000`.

What's going on here? I'm compiling with `gcc 4.8.1` on a 64-bit Ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: Why do you think the answer should be `1099511627776000000000`

Comment: @KRUKUSA 1099511627776000000000 is correct for 1000000000 << 40

Comment: Hint: Output them in hexadecimal and you probably see it ;)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The *mathematical* result of `1000000000 << 40` is `1099511627776000000000`, which exceeds 2<sup>64</sup>-1 (actually it exceeds 2<sup>69</sup>) and cannot be represented as a `uint64_t`.

For a signed left operand, this would be an overflow resulting in undefined behavior. For an unsigned left operand, the result is reduced modulo 2<sup>N</sup>, where N is the width of the left operand's type (in this case N is 64).

In hexadecimal, we have `0x3b9aca00 << 40` which yields `0x3b9aca000000000000`. Reducing this module 2<sup>64</sup> is equivalent to truncating all but the 64 low-order bits, which yields `0x9aca000000000000`, which is `11153727427136454656` in decimal.

Comment: Oh crap...can't believe I missed that.

Comment: +1 nice answer, the only thing I might add is the observation that `1000000000` > `2^29` which makes it a little more obvious that shifting by `40` will cause overflow.